# Pandas Calculate RMSE in Date Range Chunks by Year

Tags: pandas, row, calculation

I have data in a df and need to calculate the RMSE of a column consisting of rows of months and years data compared to the current month and year rows in a chunk period. I cannot figure out how to set up the sequencing by each year. For example, I need to calculate the RMSE by year from exactly month == 5 to month == 2 and print all the RMSE values in the "Variation" column by start year. My data looks like this:

```
                     month  mean_mon_flow  ...  std_anomaly  Variation
date                                       ...                        
1992-04-01 00:00:00      4      12.265100  ...    -1.074586        NaN
1992-05-01 00:00:00      5      12.533220  ...    -1.017388   0.057198
1992-06-01 00:00:00      6      12.491247  ...    -1.117406  -0.100018
1992-07-01 00:00:00      7      12.113165  ...    -1.401221  -0.283815
1992-08-01 00:00:00      8      11.846904  ...    -1.359026   0.042195
1992-09-01 00:00:00      9      11.526178  ...    -0.299250   1.059776
1992-10-01 00:00:00     10      11.555834  ...    -0.628162  -0.328911
1992-11-01 00:00:00     11      11.746104  ...    -1.116374  -0.488213
1992-12-01 00:00:00     12      11.891824  ...    -0.143343   0.973031
1993-01-01 00:00:00      1      11.997252  ...    -0.486450  -0.343107
1993-02-01 00:00:00      2      12.028855  ...    -0.862971  -0.376521
1993-03-01 00:00:00      3      12.063974  ...    -0.596869   0.266102
1993-04-01 00:00:00      4      12.265100  ...    -0.923695  -0.326826
1993-05-01 00:00:00      5      12.533220  ...     0.322987   1.246682
1993-06-01 00:00:00      6      12.491247  ...    -0.478567  -0.801554
1993-07-01 00:00:00      7      12.113165  ...    -0.274119   0.204448
1993-08-01 00:00:00      8      11.846904  ...    -0.707968  -0.433849
1993-09-01 00:00:00      9      11.526178  ...     0.167246   0.875214
1993-10-01 00:00:00     10      11.555834  ...    -0.089410  -0.256656
1993-11-01 00:00:00     11      11.746104  ...    -1.046461  -0.957050
1993-12-01 00:00:00     12      11.891824  ...    -1.293175  -0.246714
1994-01-01 00:00:00      1      11.997252  ...    -1.505133  -0.211959
1994-02-01 00:00:00      2      12.028855  ...    -0.610121   0.895012
1994-03-01 00:00:00      3      12.063974  ...    -0.974184  -0.364063
1994-04-01 00:00:00      4      12.265100  ...    -1.077609  -0.103424
```

The observed data from the current year looks like this:

```
                     month  mean_mon_flow  ...  std_anomaly  Variation
date                                       ...                        
2021-05-01 00:00:00      5      12.533220  ...    -0.935899   0.206586
2021-06-01 00:00:00      6      12.491247  ...    -0.647261   0.288638
2021-07-01 00:00:00      7      12.113165  ...    -0.711730  -0.064469
2021-08-01 00:00:00      8      11.846904  ...    -0.482306   0.229424
2021-09-01 00:00:00      9      11.526178  ...    -0.116989   0.365317
2021-10-01 00:00:00     10      11.555834  ...     0.319614   0.436603
2021-11-01 00:00:00     11      11.746104  ...     0.880379   0.560765
2021-12-01 00:00:00     12      11.891824  ...     0.630541  -0.249838
2022-01-01 00:00:00      1      11.997252  ...    -0.151507  -0.782048
2022-02-01 00:00:00      2      12.028855  ...    -0.237398  -0.085891
```

The result should be something like this below. I've tried using a groupby statement to calculate RMSE but not sure how to give groupby a range of dates.

```
year   RMSE Variation
1992   number
1993   number
1994   number 
..     ..
2020   number
```

thank you,

Comment: To clarify, in your expected output, would the row with `year == 2020` hold the RMSE of Variation for 2020 May through 2021 Feb inclusive? Do you intend to ignore data from March and April of each year?

Comment: Hi - the RMSE of Variation for year 2020 would be df.Variation from May 2020 consecutively each month to Feb 2021. I have figured a way to create a new df using isin by months [5,6,7,8,9.10,11,12,1,2] so that I'm calculating RMSE conecutvely by year using months listed above here e.g.  5,6,7,...2 if that helps. Yes, ignoring Mar, Apr in the example above. However, next month that changes with a new month so April and May are ignored in the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pre-processing of your dataframe for previous years. First, get the year label by taking the year component of your date with 4-month subtracted. Second, drop March and April.

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
df_prev['year'] = pd.Series(df_prev['date'].dt.to_pydatetime() - relativedelta(months=4)).dt.year

df_prev = df_prev[~df_prev['month'].isin([3,4])]
```

Then convert `df_prev` into a matrix with years as column and month as index, convert the table for this year into a series with month as index.

```
df_prev_vari = df_prev.set_index(['month', 'year'])[['Variation']].unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
df_this_vari = df_this.set_index('month')['Variation']
```

Having month as the common index for both data enables us to subtract one another by matching the index, followed by squared, mean, and square-root operations.

```
(df_prev_vari.sub(df_this_vari, axis=0)**2).mean()**.5
```

Comment: ok, I get 'df_this" as not defined. Is this a new df?

Comment: `df_this` is `The observed data from the current year` as described in your question.

Comment: of course, got it. many thanks,

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Comment: sorry, one more thing. what does .sub do? subtraction!

Comment: subtract. The 'E' from RMSE means Error which means to subtract. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html